# Filter array nested in array with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need help solving a problem with vue.js and the filter function

**I have this file main.js:**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data() {
        return {
        movies: [],
        liveFilter: '',
        filterActors: ''
    }
  },
   created() {
            this.$http.get(apiURL).then(response => {
                this.movies = response.data;
              }, response => {
              });
    },
    computed: {
      filteredMovies() {
       return this.movies.filter((movie) => {
       return movie.title[0].value.toLowerCase().includes(this.liveFilter.toLowerCase())
        || movie.field_director[0].value.toLowerCase().includes(this.liveFilter.toLowerCase())
        });
      },
      filteredActors() {
        return this.movies.filter((movie) => {
          return movie.field_actors.filter((actor) => {
          actor.value.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterActors.toLowerCase())
         });
        });
       }
    }
})
```

**And this index.html**

```
 <div class="container" id="app">

        <div class="filter">Filtra per parola:
            <input type="text" v-model="liveFilter">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="filter">Filtra per attiru:
            <input type="text" v-model="filterActors">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div v-for="movie in filteredMovies">
            <div class="locandina">
            <img v-bind:src=" movie.field_movie_poster[0].url " v-bind:alt="movie.field_movie_poster[0].alt">
            </div>
            <h4>{{ movie.title[0].value }}</h4>
            <p>
                <strong>Regista:</strong> {{ movie.field_director[0].value }}
            </p>

            <strong>Attori:</strong><br>
            <span v-for="actor in filteredActors">
                {{ actor.value }}<br>
            </span>
            <br>
            <strong>Genere: </strong>
            <span v-for="genere in movie.field_genere">
                {{ genere.value }},
            </span>
            <br>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, first filter computed ( function filteredMovies() ) work fine but second filter ( filteredActors() ) not work: empty span (actors) are returned. How i solve. Thanks

Comment: My advice would be to create a codepen and mock out the http call and return a static array for `this.movies`. We don't know what the data looks like.

Comment: I have posted the file json